# the data method of vector has some wrong

Tags: c++11

I use the data method of vector in C++, but I have some problems, the code is in belows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector (5);

  int* p = myvector.data();

  *p = 10;
  ++p;
  *p = 20;
  p[2] = 100;

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<myvector.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

the result is `myvector contains: 10 20 0 100 0`, but why the result is not `myvector contains: 10 20 100 0 0`, the first one `*p = 10;` is 10, the second one  `++p;*p = 20;` is 20, that's all right, but the third one `p[2] = 100;` should be 100, but it is 0, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With visuals:

```cpp
std::vector<int> myvector (5);
//   ---------------------
//   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
//   ---------------------

int* p = myvector.data();
//   ---------------------
//   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
//   ---------------------
//     ^
//     p

*p = 10;
//   ----------------------
//   | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
//   ----------------------
//     ^
//     p

++p;
//   ----------------------
//   | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
//   ----------------------
//          ^
//          p

*p = 20;
//   ----------------------
//   | 10 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
//   ----------------------
//          ^
//          p


p[2] = 100;
//   -------------------------
//   | 10 | 20 | 0 | 100 | 0 |
//   -------------------------
//          ^         ^
//          p         p[2]
```

It's helpful to remember that `p[2]` is a shorter way to say `*(p + 2)`.

Comment: Yay, Donald Knuth's style.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are modifying `p` itself.

After `++p` (which I remember you it's equivalent to `p = p + 1`), `p` points to the element at index `1`, so `p[2]` points at element at index `3` from the beginning of the vector which is why the fourth element is changed instead.

Answer (score 1):

After `++p`, pointer `p` is pointing to myvector[1].

Then we have:

- `p[0]` pointing to `myvector[1]`
- `p[1]` pointing to `myvector[2]`
- `p[2]` pointing to `myvector[3]`